# How to retrieve data Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, firebase

The problem here is that i need to somehow get the information of the user when he logs in. So what is happening is that when he register all goes fine he goes to another page and it says `"Welcome" + username` And it does it correctly! But when  i do it with the login page the username becomes undefined. Im preety sure i like somehow need to store my data in a factory but stumbled on how to. Thats what i think but may not be true. Anways...

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qB3Gkeq5ji1YQyy0kpGH

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: While a plunkr is a great way to allow someone to quickly see your problem in context, it is by itself not enough for a question on StackOverflow. When you update your plunkr, the question becomes useless to people who stumble upon it in the future. Next time *also* include the minimal code that reproduces the problem in the question itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use FirebaseAuth

in your controller you're using firebase array not Auth. This is an extract of the correct way to auth with firebase.

```
// define our app and dependencies (remember to include firebase!)
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
// inject $firebaseAuth into our controller
app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth",
  function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);
```

[Here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html) is a link to the Docs with the exact tutorial. I would advise following it all the way through to learn firebase.

Comment: It says in console ref2.authWithPassword is not a function  When i try to do it your way. This is what i did: var ref = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
     var ref2 = $firebaseAuth(ref);

Comment: This is the docs im following.. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html

Comment: That link describes email+password authentication for the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK. While AngularFire is built on top of (and interacts seamlessly with) that SDK, you'll have an easier time if you use AngularFire methods first and only fall back to regular SDK for stuff AngularFire doesn't cover. So study the [**AngularFire** API documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html), specifically [`$authWithPassword()`])(https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-authwithpasswordcredentials-options).

Comment: take some time to go through the entire doc for firebase and the tutorials for angularfire, there pretty good.